# How can i get a single prediction of a class with a Keras multiclass Sequential model?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, sequential

I build a Multiclass Sequential model with the Keras library in the following way:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
#input layer
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2])),

#hidden layer 1
keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

#hidden layer 2
keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

#hidden layer 3
keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

#output layer
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
```

])

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer = optimizer,
         loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
         metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(inputs_train, targets_train, 
      validation_data=(inputs_test, targets_test),
     epochs=10,
     batch_size=32)
```

using the dataset made from the GTZAN dataset by analyzing all the songs with the librosa library and the resulting dataset has:
10 classes: ['blues', 'classical', 'country', 'disco', 'hiphop', 'jazz', 'metal', 'pop', 'reggae', 'rock']
and every song has:
13 features: that i extracted using librosa.features.mfcc(..., n_mfcc=13, ...).

the model works fine but how can i predict only 1 class because if i run model.output_shape i get that the output is a array of (None, 10).

and if i try with a new song that is not in the dataset:

```
predict = model.predict(song)
```

predict is a vector:

```
[0.10061797 0.10143244 0.10092255 0.10302719 0.0996335  0.10174131 0.09681843 0.09491318 0.09931136 0.10158204]
```

so how can i interpret this values? Or in alternative: how can i make so that the answer is only the class he predict, so a number from 0 to 9 ?

Answer (score 0):

That vector indicate the probability for each class (if you sum them you get 1). You can get the top one trivially with the index of the max element in that:

```
predict.index(max(predict))
```

Then it's up to you to decide where just taking the max is enough or maybe it's better to consider other factor related to the probabilities (I don't know, just guessing).